# POPos 20.10 unable to install amd gpu drivers

Tags: debian, drivers, amd-graphics, proprietary-drivers, pop-os

##unable to upgrade install amd gpu drivers I tried manually doing it from the website but that failed too

here is the error code

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  fwupd fwupd-signed linux-generic linux-headers-5.11.0-7612-generic
  linux-headers-generic linux-image-5.11.0-7612-generic linux-image-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-7612-generic linux-system76
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.0.15-1098277) ...
Removing old amdgpu-5.6.0.15-1098277 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.6.0.15-1098277
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.0.15-1098277 DKMS files...
Building for 5.11.0-7612-generic
Building for architecture amd64
Building initial module for 5.11.0-7612-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.11.0-7612-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-7612-generic (amd64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.0.15-1098277); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. undo the failed install: `amdgpu-uninstall`
2. re-install without dkms: `./amdgpu-install --opencl=pal,legacy --no-dkms`